# Отмена транзакций через 72 часа на Google Play. Биллинг на Unity IAP

Tags: android, unity3d, google-play, in-app-purchases, android-billing

уважаемые коллеги. Я опубликовал недавно игру на Google Play со внедренным на продажу контентом, после чего купил у себя с другого аккаунта предмет для проверки. Спустя 72 часа платеж был возвращен.

Версия Unity - 2020.3.23f1, покупки обрабатываются библиотекой Unity IAP версии 4.1.2.
Сам процесс покупок реализован без использования кода: при нажатии игроком на IAPButton вызывается метод *OnPurchaseComplete_Car(Product product)*, который выдает предмет игроку.
Больше никакого функционала UnityPurchasing в коде нет.

Пробовал вариант "ручной" инициализации UnityPurchasing, но на смартфоне уже запущенная игра "не видела" предметов из списка продаваемого контента Google Play Console, в то время как в самом Unity все предметы работают, а цены отображаются согласно Unity IAP Catalog.
Подскажите, пожалуйста - как я мог бы дополнить код, чтобы покупки обрабатывались без дальнейшей отмены транзакций?

Comment: Покупку нужно подтверждать иначе она будет возвращаться.